# Visa for Australia and New Zealand for Indian citizen living in USA

Tags: visas, australia, indian-citizens, new-zealand

I am an Indian citizen living in the US (California) on H1B Visa. I plan to go to Australia and New Zealand for tourism. I have 2 questions -

1. Do I need a separate tourist visa for both countries?
2. What is the process to get visas for these countries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Yes, you will need separate tourist visas for each country.

2) For NZ:

- You are **not** travelling on a passport from a [visa waiver country](http://glossary.immigration.govt.nz/visafreecountries.htm), so you will need a visitor's visa
- [This link](http://www.immigration.govt.nz/migrant/stream/visit/visitors/process/default.htm) has the process for applying for a visa.
- From step 4, it would seem that you should apply to the LA branch of the New Zealand Visa Application Centre.
- Cost is US$140 + $37

For Aus:

- Similarly for Australia, you **do not** meet the requirements for an [eVisitor visa](http://www.immi.gov.au/visitors/tourist/evisitor/eligibility.htm)
- The process for applying for a tourist visa is [here](http://www.immi.gov.au/visas/visitor/600/applicants.htm)
- You will need to lodge your form(s) to the Australian embassy in Washington. Check [this page](http://www.immi.gov.au/contacts/overseas/u/united-states-of-america/visa-information.htm)
- Cost is estimated at US$130

Comment: in case you are not traveling alone, applying for a "group visa" for NZ will result in substantial financial savings. a group can be that of friends or colleagues not just family.